# 'GridView1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I have created an asp.net Web application using Vb.net and added a default.aspx page which client sent me. following is markup of page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Content/MasterPages/HaloBackOffice.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Gate_Jape_Verifications_PostGate_AuditDocument_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

In code behind, I am writing this:

```
        GridView1.DataSource = ds
        GridView1.DataBind()
        GridView1.DataMember = "DataTable"
```

but getting error:

'GridView1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Is can be reason of Page directive has different inherits value or Page was part of asp.net Website and I created Web application ?

Please suggest.